# Is it possible to make a child of a flex column be 100% width of its flex container?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the red box be the same width as the flex container outlined in black.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  column-gap: 1em;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.a {
  background: #f002;
  flex: 3;
}
.b {
  background: #00f2;
  flex: 2;
}
.box {
  background: #f0f2;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 1em;
}
.fw {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="box">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="box fw">
      B
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      C
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <p>Some text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it in this case that you have presented. The code might need to be changed if the propertion between the first column and second column change.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  column-gap: 1em;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.a {
overflow: visible;
  background: #f002;
  flex: 3;
}
.b {
  background: #00f2;
  flex: 2;
}
.box {
  background: #f0f2;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 1em;
}
.fw {
  width: calc(166.666666% - 1em);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="box">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="box fw">
      B
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      C
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <p>Some text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great. Do you have a formula to get the required percentage in case the proportions change?

Comment: Yes. The 1em would be replaced with the gap that you are using and the percentage that you would use for the width would be (flexOfBBox-flexOfABox+1) * 100